# Как проверить удовлетворяет ли хоть какой-нибудь элемент массива условию на PHP?

Tags: php

На JS для этого есть функция `some()`, есть ли аналог такой функции на PHP ?

В [списке](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.array.php) функций для работы с массивами такого не нашёл.

Мне нужно проверить есть ли в массиве хоть один элемент не являющийся пустой строкой. Попробовал `in_array(!'', $arr)`, но такая функция некорректно срабатывает если элементом массива является `'0'`. Ещё есть идея сделать так: `implode($arr) != ''`, но по-моему это не лучшее решение.

Comment: http://www.php.su/in_array

Comment: правильнее http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php

Comment: @vitidev и самое близкое, только он не остановится и вернет массив, а не булево значение

Comment: `function some($array, $function) { return count(array_filter($array,$function)) != 0; }`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Можно самостоятельно написать такую функцию, например, следующим образом

```
<?php
  function some($arr)
  {
    foreach($arr as $value) {
      if($value !== '') return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  $arr = ['', 0, '', ''];
  echo some($arr);
```

Насколько я понял из комментариев, вам важно различать пустые строки и значение 0? В этом случае при сравнении лучше использовать операторы эквивалентности `===` и неэквивалентности `!==`, которые помимо значения проверяют еще и тип переменных.

Представленный выше вариант заточен лишь на один конкретный случай, однако, если передать функции `some()` в качестве аргумента функцию обратного вызова, её можно сделать более универсальной, изменяя условия принятия решения на лету при помощи анонимной функции

```
<?php
  function some($arr, $callback)
  {
    foreach($arr as $value) {
      if($callback($value)) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  $arr = ['', 0, '', ''];
  echo some($arr, function($value){
    return $value !== '';
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам это нужно? `array_map()`. Применяет callback-функцию ко всем элементам указанных массивов

Answer (score 0):

Если просто определить есть ли значение то можно так :

```
$a = [
    "a","b","c","d","1","2"
];

echo (in_array("a" , $a) ? true : false); //true
echo (in_array("aa" , $a) ? true : false);//false

echo (array_search("c" , $a) ? true : false);//true
echo (array_search("cc" , $a) ? true : false);//false

echo (array_flip($a)['d'] ? true : false);//true
echo (array_flip($a)['dd'] ? true : false);//false
```

Answer (score 0):

array_filter не вернет пустые строки. Поэтому проверить, что все строки не пустые можно так

```
count(array_filter($array)) != 0;
```

Comment: array_filter строки из нулей тоже отсеет

Comment: Напишите кастомный колбек со строгой проверкой.

Answer (score 0):

`join($arr) != 0;` можно так попробовать, но это аналогично `implode()`
можно конечно и функцию some() написать, но думаю не стоит